# How to properly make menu responsive on mobile with Media Screen?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a responsive menu mainly in css and it works perfectly on windows resize with @media screen but on mobile it does not. On my Nokia Lumia 635 which has a 854 x 480 display, the menu is not responsive but it aligns the menu in one line, meanwhile in the browser when I resize it is responsive.

My Windows phone width is 480 so I can't tell why it is not responsive on mobile meanwhile other menus are.

[A demo can be seen here](https://holyunions.com/brouillons_menu_original.php)

Here is my code

CSS

```
<style>
/* CSS Document */

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif);

body {
    background: #212121;
    font-size:22px;
    line-height: 32px;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    word-wrap:break-word !important;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }

h1 {
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
}   

h3 {
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 34px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
}

h3 a {
    color: #FFF;
}

a {
    color: #FFF;
}

h1 {
    margin-top: 100px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:60px;
    line-height: 70px;
    font-family: 'Bree Serif', 'serif';
    }

#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 890px;
}

p {
    text-align: center;
}

.toggle,
[id^=drop] {
    display: none;
}

/* Giving a background-color to the nav container. */
nav { 
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #254441;
}

#logo {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 30px;
    float: left;
    font-size:20px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

/* Since we'll have the "ul li" "float:left"
 * we need to add a clear after the container. */

nav:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}

/* Removing padding, margin and "list-style" from the "ul",
 * and adding "position:reltive" */
nav ul {
    float: right;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    }

/* Positioning the navigation items inline */
nav ul li {
    margin: 0px;
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    background-color: #254441;
    }

/* Styling the links */
nav a {
    display:block;
    padding:14px 20px;  
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:17px;
    text-decoration:none;
}


nav ul li ul li:hover { background: #000000; }

/* Background color change on Hover */
nav a:hover { 
    background-color: #000000; 
}

/* Hide Dropdowns by Default
 * and giving it a position of absolute */
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute; 
    /* has to be the same number as the "line-height" of "nav a" */
    top: 60px; 
}

/* Display Dropdowns on Hover */
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display:inherit;
}

/* Fisrt Tier Dropdown */
nav ul ul li {
    width:170px;
    float:none;
    display:list-item;
    position: relative;
}

/* Second, Third and more Tiers 
 * We move the 2nd and 3rd etc tier dropdowns to the left
 * by the amount of the width of the first tier.
*/
nav ul ul ul li {
    position: relative;
    top:-60px;
    /* has to be the same number as the "width" of "nav ul ul li" */ 
    left:170px; 
}


/* Change ' +' in order to change the Dropdown symbol */
li > a:after { content:  ' +'; }
li > a:only-child:after { content: ''; }


/* Media Queries
--------------------------------------------- */

@media all and (max-width : 768px) {

    #logo {
        display: block;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        float: none;
    }

    nav {
        margin: 0;
    }

    /* Hide the navigation menu by default */
    /* Also hide the  */
    .toggle + a,
    .menu {
        display: none;
    }

    /* Stylinf the toggle lable */
    .toggle {
        display: block;
        background-color: #254441;
        padding:14px 20px;  
        color:#FFF;
        font-size:17px;
        text-decoration:none;
        border:none;
    }

    .toggle:hover {
        background-color: #000000;
    }

    /* Display Dropdown when clicked on Parent Lable */
    [id^=drop]:checked + ul {
        display: block;
    }

    /* Change menu item's width to 100% */
    nav ul li {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        }

    nav ul ul .toggle,
    nav ul ul a {
        padding: 0 40px;
    }

    nav ul ul ul a {
        padding: 0 80px;
    }

    nav a:hover,
    nav ul ul ul a {
        background-color: #000000;
    }

    nav ul li ul li .toggle,
    nav ul ul a,
  nav ul ul ul a{
        padding:14px 20px;  
        color:#FFF;
        font-size:17px; 
    }


    nav ul li ul li .toggle,
    nav ul ul a {
        background-color: #212121; 
    }

    /* Hide Dropdowns by Default */
    nav ul ul {
        float: none;
        position:static;
        color: #ffffff;
        /* has to be the same number as the "line-height" of "nav a" */
    }

    /* Hide menus on hover */
    nav ul ul li:hover > ul,
    nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display: none;
    }

    /* Fisrt Tier Dropdown */
    nav ul ul li {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }

    nav ul ul ul li {
        position: static;
        /* has to be the same number as the "width" of "nav ul ul li" */ 

    }

}

@media all and (max-width : 330px) {

    nav ul li {
        display:block;
        width: 94%;
    }

}
</style>
```

Html

```
<nav>
   <div id="logo">Your Logo here</div>
   <label for="drop" class="toggle">Menu</label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="drop" />
   <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li>
         <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
         <label for="drop-1" class="toggle">WordPress +</label>
         <a href="#">WordPress</a>
         <input type="checkbox" id="drop-1"/>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Themes and stuff</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Plugins</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
         <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
         <label for="drop-2" class="toggle">Web Design +</label>
         <a href="#">Web Design</a>
         <input type="checkbox" id="drop-2"/>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
            <li>
               <!-- Second Tier Drop Down -->        
               <label for="drop-3" class="toggle">Tutorials +</label>
               <a href="#">Tutorials</a>         
               <input type="checkbox" id="drop-3"/>
               <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">HTML/CSS</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Graphic Design</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Man Of God</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Jesus is God</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> I AM FOR JESUS</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
<DIV>
   <p> A simple dropdown navigation menu made with CSS Only. Dropdowns are marked with a plus sign ( + )</p>
   <p> Resize the screen to see the look if the screen is smaller then 768px  <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      JESUS IS THE ONE AND ONLY TRUE GOD. ACCEPT JESUS TODAY AND YOU WILL BE SAVED. Jesus can deliver you from the power of Juju, witchraft... as He did for me 19 years ago. 
   </p>
</DIV>
```

How to properly make the menu responsive on mobile small screen with @media screen?

Comment: For common small devices @media all and (min-width:400px) and (max-width:480px){}

Comment: You've got to watch out for those witch rafts, they can whizz past in an instant. Keep your eye out for them, folks! I wonder if they're broom-powered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've forgot to use meta: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: Thumbs up but please explain why this solves the solution.

Comment: this makes the browser to see your device actual screen width and not behave like it is a desktop screen width. Check [this](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag--webdesign-5972) for a more complete explanation